# unset duplicates in multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Anyone to assist. I want to eliminate duplicates on `mcs_client_ec_no` on the below array but can't figure out how.

```
Array
(

[1] => Array
    (
        [mps_client_ec_no] => REG5
        [mcs_client_ec_no] => GL98888
        [mps_school_id] => 6
        [mcs_school_id] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [mps_client_ec_no] => TAS4752
        [mcs_client_ec_no] => ALF1252
        [mps_school_id] => 14
        [mcs_school_id] => 14
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [mps_client_ec_no] => MAP002
        [mcs_client_ec_no] => ALF1252
        [mps_school_id] => 14
        [mcs_school_id] => 14
    )

)
```

Comment: You have a numeric array that contains associative arrays, each one seemingly of a fixed structure.

In the case of de-duplicating, do you want to remove the entire associative array that is duplicate? In your example, this would mean that the output would be the same as the input.

Comment: @Mark. Yes I want to remove the entire associative array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$u = array(0=>array("mcs_client_ec_no" => GL98888,"mps_school_id" => 14),1=>array("mcs_client_ec_no" => GL98888,"mps_school_id" => 154)); 

array_unique($u);
```